# Safe to use this repository in a production environment?

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I need to know if it would be safe to add this repository to a server in production?

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

`testing` is in the location.. so I'm not sure if it would be safe to use this repository in a production environment

Comment: To me, putting software that is marked explicitly as testing into a production environment is a no-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, it's not "stable". While the `testing` repository (currently Debian [Buster](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBuster)) probably works without problems, I certainly wouldn't risk it.

Or as the Debian guys say ([DebianStable](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStable)):

> The release of Debian called "stable" is always the official released version of [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/Debian). Ordinary users should use this version. See also [DebianStability](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStability).

and a quote from [DebianStability](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStability):

> *Testing* is just what it says it is; it's for testing whether it works
>   reliably prior to its release as a future *Stable*. You may well find
>   *Testing* or *Unstable* reliable enough, and in fact others have remarked
>   that Debian *Unstable* is more reliable than some other distributions'
>   *Stable* releases.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks.. But could I just change `testing` with `jessie` be "stable"? like this `deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free`

Comment: The current stable release is `stretch` (`buster`'s planned release date is [2019-07-06](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2019/06/msg00003.html)). If you are currently running `jessie` (check with `lsb_release -a` or `cat /etc/os-release`), then you should upgrade to `stretch` first. Then you can change `testing` to `stretch`  (or `stable`) in your `sources.list`.